# can't shut it down or reboot my ubuntu 15.04

Tags: shutdown

I have my asus x551ma, I installed Ubuntu 15,04 and it was working good but, now I can't shut it down or reboot or even logging out from the corner above. 
It only works when I use terminal by typing:

```
sudo  shutdown -p now
```

but not the other normal way. Please is there anybody that can help me?